# hibernate error field doesnt have default value

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data

I am using hibernate and spring data for handling db. I am getting below error. I tried setting default value in db as well but nothing seems to solving this issue. what i have done wrong:

error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'USERNAME' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2535)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1911)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2145)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2081)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2066)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
```

table query:

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `USERNAME` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `IS_ACTIVE` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `PHONE` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`USERNAME`)
```

user pojo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "User")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "IS_ACTIVE", nullable = false)
    private boolean isActive;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "phone", nullable = false)
    private String phone;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private UserRole userRole;

}
```

removed setters and getters for better readability.

Comment: Can you provide a java code, where you create User object and persist it in the database?

Answer (score 0):

"Username" is a primary key in table "User", so it must have unique value and **cannot be null**. So you have to set a proper value for field "username" before persisting User entity.